# Flutter facing Android resource linking failed when trying to facebook intigreate. How to solve?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing this error when I am trying to implement Facebook auth in the flutter. Please help me to solve this. I follow the Facebook auth flutter documentation to that. I add app name in strings.xml in res>value>string.xml

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Flutter apps\fastvai\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:87: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.fastvai.com:string/app_name) not found.

I add strings.xml in the res>values folder but facing this error.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Fastvai</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">xx</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbxx</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token">xxxxx</string>

 </resources>
```

my app-level manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fastvai.com">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
   <application
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyCdlaI2VvSQ6nSxth7U7Zsr9Hc3_XVtdBA"/>
        android:label="Fastvai"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
       android:label="@string/app_name" />
   <activity
       android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score -2):

Fastvai
maybe not Fastvai.
appname may be different. Please make it the same as the appname at the top left of the site.